# How do I convert a JS date to excel date?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a JS date, be it in any format:

```
25/11/2021

25-11-2021

11/25/2021....
```

to it's Excel equivalent date number. My code to convert the date is as follows:

```
function JSDateToExcelDate(inDate) {  
     let date = new Date(inDate);
     var returnDateTime = 25569.0 + ((date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     return returnDateTime.toString().substr(0,5);        
}
```

When I pass a string date (for eg: `JSDateToExcelDate("25/11/2021")`) into the above mentioned function, I get the result as `NaN`. How do I get the desired result?

In other words, what is the `DATEVALUE("25/11/2021")` equivalent of excel in javascript?

Comment: What's the format excel you expect?

Comment: It should be equal to the `DATEVALUE('25/11/2021')`  formula in Excel

Comment: Your code works with valid dates. What you pass is invalid and `let date = new Date(inDate);` reports as `Invalid date`. Try using momentJs to parse from more formats

Comment: you need to add some logic to respect the format `'YYYY-MM-dd'` which `JS Date` object take, see my answer!

Comment: The thing is that the `inDate` argument is fetched from a sheet file where the values can be in any format i.e., `dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, YYYY-MM-dd, YYYY-MM-dd h:m:s, etc`

Comment: @Noob I've provided a work-around to your problem. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for. You'll realize that I've used the base date value of `1899-11-30` which seems to be preferred in this case.

```js
//  Date needs to come in format "YYYY-MM-DD"
function convertToExcelDate(date)
{
    //This local function deals with date formatting only.
    // - Here date may come in any format. YYYY-MM-DD or DD-MM-YYYY or "/" may be used
    function _formatDate(date)
    {
        var formattedDate = date.replace(/\//g,"-");
        var isRightFormat = formattedDate.indexOf("-") === 4; // True if date is in form YYYY-MM-DD

        if(!isRightFormat)
        {
            var [DD, MM, YYYY] = formattedDate.split("-");
            formattedDate = `${YYYY}-${MM}-${DD}`;
        }

        return formattedDate;
    }
    
    var _date = Date.parse(_formatDate(date));
    
    return parseInt(Math.round((_date - new Date(1899,11,30)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(10));
}

function convertInput()
{
    var _in = document.getElementById("input");
    if(_in.value) 
        console.log(convertToExcelDate(_in.value));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="convert-button" onClick="convertInput();">Convert</button>
```

Tests done with the following values:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***IDK*** How Excel DATEVALUE Function formula works, ***BUT*** I do know that `new Date(datestring)` take an argument `datestring` string respect date format of `"YYYY-MM-dd"`!

```js
function JSDateToExcelDate(inDate) {
    let [dd,MM,YYYY] = inDate.split('/');
     let date = new Date(`${YYYY}-${MM}-${dd}`);
    //...
}
```